# sql server ...Subquery returned more than

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
id      record_name     record_value
-------------------------------------
1001    price1          12
1001    price2          1
1001    price3          8
1201    price1          18
1201    price2          2
1201    price3          6
1601    price1          12
1601    price2          8
1601    price3          8
```

output

```
id      price1      value       price2      value       price3      value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001    price1      12          price2      1           price3      8
1201    price1      18          price2      2           price3      6
```

I am getting error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I used this query:

```
select distinct 
    a.id, 'Price1', 
    (select record_value 
     from table_name 
     where id = a.id and record_name = 'price1') as 'value1',
    'Price2', 
    (select record_value 
     from table_name 
     where id = a.id and record_name = 'price2') as 'value2',
    'Price3', 
    (select record_value 
     from table_name 
     where id = a.id and record_name = 'price3') as 'value3' 
from 
    table_name a
```

Please try to solve this!

Comment: So which DBMS is it? Postgres? SQL Server? SQLite?

Comment: Good question. Which one

Comment: With the data you have posted here .. there's no error like that ..it's working fine..

Comment: Also for a given id if you have multiple rows for a `record_name` say price1 , which one you want to pick or how you want to manipulate the `record_value` in that case.

Comment: any one is there..plz ans this

Comment: Do check my answer and tell me what you got.

Answer (score 5):

It is a little bit different the approach. But you could do this:

```
SELECT
    table_name.id,
    'price1' AS price1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN record_name='price1' THEN record_value ELSE 0 END) AS value1,
    'price2' AS price2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN record_name='price2' THEN record_value ELSE 0 END) AS value2,
    'price3' AS price2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN record_name='price3' THEN record_value ELSE 0 END) AS value3
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    table_name.id
```

**Update**

To reply to to comment. Yes it will work. If we look at a simple test like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, test VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1,'foo'),
(1,'foo'),
(1,'bar'),
(1,'bar')
```

This query will work having a static value as price1.

```
SELECT
    tbl.ID,
    'price1' as price1
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
GROUP BY
    tbl.ID
```

**Update 2**

Then if you do not want to `SUM` the values. Then you can use `MAX` instead. Like this:

```
SELECT
    table_name.id,
    'price1' AS price1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN record_name='price1' THEN record_value ELSE 0 END) AS value1,
    'price2' AS price2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN record_name='price2' THEN record_value ELSE 0 END) AS value2,
    'price3' AS price2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN record_name='price3' THEN record_value ELSE 0 END) AS value3
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    table_name.id
```

Comment: As price1, price2, ..etc are included in the Group by, will this query work?

Comment: Arion, Nice example. i was in doubt whether static column value are required in group by or not. Now, its clear.

Comment: i dont want to sum the values..i need as i is!

Comment: i do not want sum, max, min or another agrigations...i need the values as it is ! plz help me

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your query by adding 'top 1' to the query to avoid the error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'.
Do check it and update your status.

```
select distinct 
    a.id, 'Price1', 
    (select top 1 record_value 
     from table_name 
     where id = a.id and record_name = 'price1') as 'value1',
    'Price2', 
    (select top 1 record_value 
     from table_name 
     where id = a.id and record_name = 'price2') as 'value2',
    'Price3', 
    (select top 1 record_value 
     from table_name 
     where id = a.id and record_name = 'price3') as 'value3' 
from 
    table_name a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Distinct in the sub queries. Its not the best solution but it works.

```
select distinct 
a.id, 'Price1', 
(select distinct record_value 
 from table_name 
 where id = a.id and record_name = 'price1') as 'value1',
'Price2', 
(select distinct record_value 
 from table_name 
 where id = a.id and record_name = 'price2') as 'value2',
'Price3', 
(select distinct record_value 
 from table_name 
 where id = a.id and record_name = 'price3') as 'value3' 
from 
table_name a
```